# Gradient descent / Adam converging to suboptimal solutions

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

I am using neural nets to find the minimum of a complex function to which I compute the mean (crit in my code). Here is my net :

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.selu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.selu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

And here is the optimization loop:

```
    params = list(net.parameters())
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params, lr=learning_rate,betas=(moment[0], moment[1]), amsgrad=True)
    for i in range(nb_train):        
        for k_ in range(nb_mean):                          
            value = f(many arguments)
            crit = crit + value     
        crit = crit / nb_mean
        crit.backward(retain_graph=True)        
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

The net b is hidden inside crit.

Besides, I know a very bad approximation b_approx of the minimum b_opt. But strangely, this approximation is better than what the net gives me. So in place of b, I have put b+b_approx, where hopefully |b_approx| >> |b|.

Moreover:

- I have tuned the learning rate (from 1e-1 to 1e-100 which is really weird) and the momentum
- I have chosen multiple activation function and to my understanding, selu is generally the best choice.
- The default initialization of the weights seems optimal in Pytorch, but I am not an expert
- I have normalized the inputs
- I have tried SGD and Adam.
- I have tried simpler neural nets, such as a unique layer without activation function.

Could anybody give me an idea as to why the gradient descent converges to suboptimal solutions and how to correct it ? And also, the gradient descent always has spikes, however smal the learning rate : is it a usual behaviour for a loss function ?

Comment: Gradient descent simply isn't a very good optimizer, so it's not surprising. http://www.argmin.net/2017/12/05/kitchen-sinks/ Moreover, if the function under optimization is non-convex, then it's not guaranteed to ever find a globally minimal solution.  Including more hidden units might help. Or just doing more updates. Without a reproducible example, you're unlikely to get more specific advice. Also, AMS grad might not actually fix the problem it's designed to solve, and could even make it worse. (There was a paper that I can't find right this second.)

Comment: If you have a deterministic objective, for sufficiently small learning rate you will observe a decreasing line when plotting cost over time (sometimes you have to go really small , like lr = 1e-10, but you will always get there). If you are observing spikes for even the smallest learning rate something is wrong.

Comment: @JohnMadden that's what I thought. But my objective function is a sample mean of a stochastic quantity. Therefore, could the noise of this estimator be the reason why they are always spikes, no matter how small the learning rate is ?

Comment: @Andrew oh yeah no of course stochastic optimization will be different (I did specifically say deterministic ;)). You're in luck though: by fixing the seed of your stochastic optimization, you can derive a fixed problem, called the Sample Average Approximation. This may help with debugging (as you will then be able to see the behavior I described).